# Can't Parse Json. Raw Result .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, swagger-ui

I've developed a new .NET Core WEB API with a Get End point which returns Json data  that works great locally, however when I upload the same code to server, When i access the GET end point I get  "Can't Parse Json. Raw result" error. I've spent HOURS searching the web, reading forums, etc.. and have been able to find no resolution, so I'm asking here as my last effort.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include more detail, such as code we could use to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your nuget packages references, you might not be referencing some dependency correctly.